# Null reference exception when passing EditText as parameter

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm currently getting a null reference exception in Xamarin.Android on the call to sendChildInfoToMainForm() below. I have no problem manipulating the properties of either object prior to passing it, and when the exception is thrown the inspector doesn't show either object as null. Any ideas what might be happening here? I'm baffled although I feel like it must be something simple.

```
public override Android.Views.View OnCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.popupAddChild, container, true);

        Dialog.SetTitle ("New Child");

        EditText childFirstName_editText = view.FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.editTextChildFirstName);
        DatePicker childDOB_datePicker = view.FindViewById<DatePicker> (Resource.Id.datePickerChidDOB);
        Button submitChild = view.FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.buttonAddChild);

        childDOB_datePicker.SpinnersShown = true;

        //set up min and max dates
        DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        TimeSpan diff = System.DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-26) - origin;
        childDOB_datePicker.MinDate = (long) Math.Floor(diff.TotalSeconds);

        //wire up the button
        submitChild.Click += delegate { sendChildInfoToMainForm(childFirstName_editText, childDOB_datePicker); };

        return view;
    }

    private void sendChildInfoToMainForm(EditText kidName, DatePicker kidDOB)
    {
        ((AddMemberActivity) this.Activity).currentNewMember.childName1 = kidName.Text;
        ((AddMemberActivity) this.Activity).currentNewMember.childDOB1 = kidDOB.DateTime.ToShortDateString();
        Dismiss ();
    }
```

Comment: I should also add that this is in a fragment... If that means anything (although I have several other fragments where things like this work just fine)

Comment: @Elltz here you go: http://pastebin.com/pirchjpy

Comment: I have also uploaded the application output from the Xamarin IDE: http://pastebin.com/CzNeNNFC

Comment: What is the actual exception that is thrown? kidName and kidDOB should not be null. However, are you sure that currentNewMember is not null? I don't see where that is set.

Comment: @Kiliman currentNewMember is set outside of the code I posted (it is global to the class). the code breaks where I delegate submitChild.Click and the inspector shows childFirstName and childDOB as having content (not null).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put in a breakpoint and debug your way out of it. My suspicion is that it is actually not the `kidName` nor `kidDOB` that are null, but rather your crazy casting and your assumption that you can set your data in the `Activity` like you are doing.

A better way of achieving what you are doing is to make the `DialogFragment` not knowing anything about the `Activity` showing it. This also makes it a lot easier to reuse it in other places in the `Activity` if you need to do that at some point.

So instead of having the method `sendChildInfoToMainForm`. I would instead create an event, passing the actual data, such that the `Activity` can handle what to do with it, rather than giving the `DialogFragment` this responsibility.

```
public class ChildDialogEventArgs : EventArgs {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
}

public delegate void ChildDialogEventHandler(object sender, ChildDialogEventArgs e);
```

Then in your `DialogFragment`:

```
public event ChildDialogEventHandler Changed;
```

and then in your `Click` event do this instead:

```
submitChild.Click += (_, __) => {
    var handler = Changed;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new ChildDialogEventArgs {
            Name = childFirstName_editText.Text,
            DateOfBirth = childDOB_datePicker.DateTime
        });
}
```

Then in your `Activity` you simply need to subscribe to the `Changed` event of your `DialogFragment` and handle what to do with the data there.

Comment: The odd part here is that even when I comment out my casting and do a clean/rebuild, it still breaks. I'm beginning to think this is a Xamarin bug and I just need to recreate the delegate. As I'm new to Android, I haven't created my own events before but I'll definitely give it a try and report back.

Comment: Well something strange happened here. Re typed the view and it worked. Thanks for posting the event-driven implementation here as well, I've yet to find a better explanation of how C# handles them.